# Can I host a WCF service from within COM+?

Tags: .net, wcf, com+

New to WCF, but familiar with COM+ - can I wrap a WCF service inside a COM+ application?

I realize many people may ignore the question and question my motive (and that's fine), but I'd actually like to know if this is fundamentally possible as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can and the excellent Christian Weyer can show you how:

http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2006/07/01/414626.aspx

And more on the specifics on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733094.aspx